# Different textarea elements on different pages

Tags: html, css

I want to place different `textarea`s on different pages. The *CSS* for the `textarea` seems to be overriding the *rows* and *cols* I try to set for the second `textarea`. I've tried "*textarea*" and "*textarea1*", but that obviously didn't work.

```css
textarea {
  width: 40%;
  height: 75px;
  padding: 12px 20px ;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 5px solid #D8FF01;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bolder; 
  resize: both;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <textarea name="comment" placeholder="Enter text here"></textarea>
</form>

<form>    
  <textarea name="reason" placeholder="Enter text here: (500 characters maximum)" maxlength="500" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: You have multiple selectors to choose from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use like this

```css
textarea:not(.reason) {
    width: 40%;
    height: 75px;
    padding: 12px 20px ;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 5px solid #D8FF01;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #000;
    color: white;
    font-weight:bolder; 
    resize:both;
}
```

```html
<form>
<textarea name="comment" placeholder="Enter text here"></textarea>
</form>

<form>    
<textarea name="reason" class="reason" placeholder="Enter text here: (500 characters maximum)" maxlength="500" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
</form>
```

in this way, `CSS selector` uses `class` of element.

### or

```css
textarea.myTextBox {
  width: 40%;
  height: 75px;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 5px solid #D8FF01;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bolder;
  resize: both;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <textarea name="comment" class="myTextBox" placeholder="Enter text here"></textarea>
</form>

<form>
  <textarea name="reason" placeholder="Enter text here: (500 characters maximum)" maxlength="500" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this

**HTML:**

```
<form>
 <textarea class="textarea1" name="comment" placeholder="Enter text here"> 
 </textarea>
</form>

<form>    
 <textarea class="textarea2" name="reason" placeholder="Enter text here: (500 characters maximum)" maxlength="500" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
</form>
```

**CSS:**

```
.textarea1 {
  width: 40%;
  height: 75px;
  padding: 12px 20px ;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 5px solid #D8FF01;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
  font-weight:bolder; 
  resize:both;
}

.textarea2 {
  width: 40%;
  height: 75px;
  padding: 12px 20px ;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 5px solid #D8FF01;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
  font-weight:bolder; 
  resize:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to just do a separate css for both by using class so:

```
<form>
    <textarea class="xxx" name="comment" placeholder="Enter text here">
    </textarea>
</form>

<form>    
     <textarea class="yyy" name="reason" placeholder="Enter text here: (500 characters maximum)" maxlength="500" rows="10" cols="50">
     </textarea>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
.xxx {
    enter styling code here
}

.yyy {
    enter styling code here
}
```